# Player does not take damage when near enemy

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want the player to take damage whenever the enemy is near, the enemy will take damage but the player doesn't(i tried taking away the function that kills the enemy to check if it is too quick). I am quite new to unity and this is one of my first "independent" scripts, so it may be a quite obvious error. There are no errors or warnings however.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AttackableScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public float health;
    public float attackSpeed;
    public float damage;
    public float radious = 3f;
    public Transform enemyArea;
    bool dead = false;
    public GameObject player;

    public float KillCount;

    public void Die()
    {
        Debug.Log(health);
        health = health - 0.04f;
        if (health == 0f)
        {
            dead = true;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator Attack()
    {
         GameObject thePlayer = GameObject.Find("player");
         PlayerMovement playerScript = thePlayer.GetComponent<PlayerMovement>();

         playerScript.playerHealth = playerScript.playerHealth - damage;
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(attackSpeed);
         Debug.Log("player health = " + playerScript.playerHealth);
    }

    void Update() {
        float distance = Vector3.Distance(player.transform.position, enemyArea.position);
        if (distance <= radious && dead != true)
        {
            Attack();
        }

        if (health <= 0)
        {
            health = 0;
            Destroy(gameObject);
            Destroy(this);
        }
    }
}
```

the game is 2d.

Comment: Unity has some method for handling object collision: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html

Comment: that isnt the issue

Comment: check the top, theres an error when i try to edit it

Comment: Can you add some debugging steps? Have you watched it to see the state and order?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Why is Attack() a yield-return enumerator? The actual code maybe won't get called unless you try to enumerate the result, which you don't.

Comment: Again i am new, but i used enumerator since that is the only function that use use WaitForSeconds @Rup

Answer (score 0):

I asked a discord and they pointed out my misuse of coroutines, i forgot to start one when i called the attack function. So instead of Attack() , it was StartCoroutine(Attack());